# StreamSocket.InputStreamOptions.ReadAsync hangs when using Wait()

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-store-apps

This is the smallest possible scenario, I was able to prepare:

- This code connects to imap.gmail.com
- Reads the initial server greeting (using Read method)
- Sends NOOP command (NO Operation)
- Reads NOOP command response (again using Read method)

The problem is that the **second Read hangs**. It works perfectly if 'await ReadAsync' is used.

When I break the program I can see the Call Stack starts at task.Wait() and ends on System.Threading.Monitor.Wait().

If I debug this step by step, it does not hang. I must admit it looks like a .NET framework bug, but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

```
private static async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync(StreamSocket socket)
{
    // all responses are smaller that 1024
    IBuffer buffer = new byte[1024].AsBuffer();
    await socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(
            buffer, buffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
    return buffer.ToArray();
}

private static byte[] Read(StreamSocket socket)
{
    Task<byte[]> task = ReadAsync(socket);
    task.Wait();
    return task.Result;
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1250");

    using (StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket())
    {
        await socket.ConnectAsync(
            new HostName("imap.gmail.com"), "993", SocketProtectionLevel.Ssl);

        // notice we are using Wait() version here without any problems:
        byte[] serverGreetings = Read(socket);              

        await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(
            encoding.GetBytes("A0001 NOOP\r\n").AsBuffer());
        await socket.OutputStream.FlushAsync();

        //byte[] noopResponse = await ReadAsync(socket);    // works
        byte[] noopResponse = Read(socket);                 // hangs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I explain the cause of this deadlock [in my recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) as well as [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The short answer is that you're not *supposed* to call `Wait` or `Result` on `async` code; you should use `await` all the way.

Comment: Can you explain why doesn't the first Read block?

Comment: It will only deadlock if the task is not yet complete by the time `Wait` is called (I assume that the gmail server is immediately sending data when it accepts the connection, but you have to wait for a reply to a command). This is also why it works in the debugger.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. Still, although I understand why it deadlocks, it seems like a bug.

Comment: What behavior would make more sense? Really, the only option would have been to change the default behavior of `async` methods so that they do not resume on their context. But in that case you would still have the same deadlock if you do "opt in" to the context. There's no way to avoid the deadlock completely.