# How to read and send data to client from server?

Tags: c#, sockets, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make a server client using a local console server on my pc and a client on windows phone 8.1. The problem that I have is that I don't know how to read the incoming data from the client. I've searched the internet and read serveral microsoft tutorials but they do not explain how to read the incoming data in the server. Here's what I have.

Client on windows phone 8.1:

```
private async void tryConnect()
{
    if (connected)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Already connected";
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        // serverHostnameString = "127.0.0.1"
        // serverPort = "1330"
        StatusLabel.Text = "Trying to connect ...";
        serverHost = new HostName(serverHostnameString);
        // Try to connect to the 
        await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverPort);
        connected = true;
        StatusLabel.Text = "Connection established" + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // If this is an unknown status, 
        // it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
        if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
        {
            throw;
        }
        StatusLabel.Text = "Connect failed with error: " + exception.Message;
        // Could retry the connection, but for this simple example
        // just close the socket.

        closing = true;
        // the Close method is mapped to the C# Dispose
        clientSocket.Dispose();
        clientSocket = null;
    }
}

private async void sendData(string data)
{
    if (!connected)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Must be connected to send!";
        return;
    }
    UInt32 len = 0; // Gets the UTF-8 string length.

    try
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Trying to send data ...";

        // add a newline to the text to send
        string sendData = "jo";
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(clientSocket.OutputStream);
        len = writer.MeasureString(sendData); // Gets the UTF-8 string length.

        // Call StoreAsync method to store the data to a backing stream
        await writer.StoreAsync();

        StatusLabel.Text = "Data was sent" + Environment.NewLine;

        // detach the stream and close it
        writer.DetachStream();
        writer.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // If this is an unknown status, 
        // it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
        if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
        {
            throw;
        }

        StatusLabel.Text = "Send data or receive failed with error: " + exception.Message;
        // Could retry the connection, but for this simple example
        // just close the socket.

        closing = true;
        clientSocket.Dispose();
        clientSocket = null;
        connected = false;

    }
}
```

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150599.aspx)

And the server:

```
public class Server
{
    private TcpClient incomingClient;

    public Server()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1330);
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
        while (true)
        {
            //AcceptTcpClient waits for a connection from the client
            incomingClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //start a new thread to handle this connection so we can go back to waiting for another client
            Thread thread = new Thread(HandleClientThread);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start(incomingClient);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClientThread(object obj)
    {
        TcpClient client = obj as TcpClient;

        Console.WriteLine("Connection found!");
        while (true)
        {
            //how to read and send data back?
        }
    }
}
```

It comes to the point where the server prints 'Connection found!', but I don't know how to go further.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

Now my handleclientthread method looks like this:

```
private void HandleClientThread(object obj)
{
    TcpClient client = obj as TcpClient;
    netStream = client.GetStream();
    byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[500]; // Receive buffer
    int bytesRcvd; // Received byte count
    int totalBytesEchoed = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Connection found!");
    while (true)
    {
        while ((bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                netStream.Write(rcvBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);
                totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(totalBytesEchoed);
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't write the bytes to the console

Comment: Search for TCPClient sample code.  Here's one:

http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2013/12/basic-tcp-socket-echo-client-server.html

Comment: @MattSmall This is not what I'm looking for. It's irrelevant because my client (windows phone 8.1) doesn't know TcpClient, NetworkStream etc. I just want to know how I can manage to communicate from my windows phone to a console server and vice versa.

Comment: But your server does, and that's what you're using on the console.  Am I missing something here?  You've already indicated that your phone is sending data to the server, but you don't know how to read it.

Comment: @MattSmall Made a edit to my main post, I added the code from the site to my server but it still doesn't write to console.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using TCP and sockets instead of a high-level communication stack, like WCF, or Web API, or something else?

Comment: Haven't learned those (yet?) at school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... after a lot of searching the internet I have found a solution...

Server: to read from the server and send data back to the phone:

```
   // method in a new thread, for each connection
    private void HandleClientThread(object obj)
    {
        TcpClient client = obj as TcpClient;
        netStream = client.GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection found!");

        while (true)
        {
            // read data
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int totalRead = 0;
            do
            {
                int read = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, totalRead, buffer.Length - totalRead);
                totalRead += read;
            } while (client.GetStream().DataAvailable);

            string received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, totalRead);
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse from client: {0}", received);

            // do some actions
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(received);


            // send data back
            client.GetStream().WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

Phone(client): to send messages from the phone and read the messages from server:

```
 private async void sendData(string dataToSend)
 // import for AsBuffer(): using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    {
        if (!connected)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Status: Must be connected to send!";
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            byte[] data = GetBytes(dataToSend);
            IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();

            StatusLabel.Text = "Status: Trying to send data ...";
            await clientSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);

            StatusLabel.Text = "Status: Data was sent" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }

            StatusLabel.Text = "Status: Send data or receive failed with error: " + exception.Message;
            closing = true;
            clientSocket.Dispose();
            clientSocket = null;
            connected = false;
        }
        readData();
    }

    private async void readData()
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Trying to receive data ...";
        try
        {
            IBuffer buffer = new byte[1024].AsBuffer();
            await clientSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, buffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
            byte[] result = buffer.ToArray();
            StatusLabel.Text = GetString(result);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }

            StatusLabel.Text = "Receive failed with error: " + exception.Message;
            closing = true;
            clientSocket.Dispose();
            clientSocket = null;
            connected = false;
        }
    }
```

The 'await clientSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, buffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.Partial)' command in the readData method was very unclear for me. I didn't know you had to make a new buffer, and the ReadAsync-method fills it(as i inderstand it). Found it here: [StreamSocket.InputStreamOptions.ReadAsync hangs when using Wait()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436824/streamsocket-inputstreamoptions-readasync-hangs-when-using-wait)